# I got rejected and now they called again

Tags: interviewing, job-search, job-offer, rejection

I am a college student looking for his first internship. Not long ago I applied for a big multinational pharmaceutical company which they called and set up the interview. Everything went perfect to say the least, a 45 minute interview went on for more than an hour and even had another interview with the manager of that area in the same day. Unfortunately after a couple of weeks I was informed I was rejected because of lack of experience. A month or so passed and I got a phone call from the recruiter saying that the position I originally applied is taken but since I left a good impression on the managers  and him he wants to consider me for another position within the company. other questions was if I was in the hiring process of another company and if I am still  applying to other companies. So, is it a good sign? am I hired?  has this happened to anyone? Any advice on what should I do?

Thanks

Comment: Are you interested? If so, say yes, and ask the next steps you can expect for this position.

Answer (score 21):

Sounds like the company didn't think you were a good fit for the first position you interviewed for, but now they have another opening that is a better fit. You left a good impression and they would like to consider you for this new position. The key word is ***consider***. You do not have the job yet, but there is a good chance you will get it. This does happen from time-to-time especially in big companies.

Ultimately, ***this sounds like a good thing***. My advice is to pursue and see what they offer you, but don't stop interviewing with other companies until you accept a job.

Comment: The last part is the most important. Keep as much options open as possible.

Answer (score 4):

So you apparently left a good impression with the first interview ... just not good ENOUGH to get the job. Maybe that job required more experience, but now they have another job opening that doesn't require as much experience. Or maybe another applicant impressed them more and they hired him, but you were a close second.

In any case, assuming that you are still interested in working for this company after the first interview, I'd pursue it essentially like it's a totally new interview. Don't assume the job is yours for the taking just because they called you. There may be shortcuts in the process because you've already been through an interview there, but don't make assumptions. Let them tell you what their process is.

Don't abandon any other options you may be pursuing. You have no guarantee that this will work out.